# How to close a socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, sockets

I can't figure out hot to disconnect an established socket.io connection.
It is simple socket.io configuration:

```
var app_rf = http.createServer(function(req, res) {});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app_rf);
app_rf.listen(3001);
```

I send data via:

```
 io.sockets.emit('series_results', result_rf );
```

and read it in the browser with:

```
 var socket = io.connect('//localhost:3001');
 socket.on('series_results', function(data) {
 $('.results_rf').append("<p class='output_rf'>Gender- "+data+"</p>");
 });
```

I try with    io.disconnect('//localhost:3001') on the client, but does not work. 
My problem is that as the connection is not closed, the messages are kept, instead of destroyed. If I can destroy the messages, that would also work for me.

Comment: `$('.result_rf').html('');`?

Comment: been there. on next request all previous messages come back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve it: 
I added this to the server code

```
io.sockets.on('disconnect', function() {
// handle disconnect
io.sockets.disconnect();
io.sockets.close();});
```

and edited this on the client:

```
 var socket = io.connect('//localhost:3001',{'forceNew':true });
```

Comment: Note that `.disconnect()` calls `.close()`, therefore the last line is not needed: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/client.js#L108-L122